# Flex Progress event bytesTotal Returns 0 in Linux

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am using URLLoader to load a remote file. Inside the progressevent I tried to take the bytesLoaded and bytesTotal from the progressevent.

Both are working fine in a windows server

But in case of a linux server that have some proxies configured bytesTotal returns 0 and bytesLoaded returns the correct value as usual. Anybody know what the issue is? Do we need to configure something inside the proxy or the linux server to get the totalbytes?

Answer (score 1):

Getting 0 for `bytesTotal` indicates the the response is being sent as a [chunked transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). Typically you see this when the server does not set the Content-length header. In your case, it would appear the proxy may not be passing the Content-length on when relaying the response.

When you receive the `Event.COMPLETE`, the length of `event.data` is the total bytes received.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS`, then.
Use `Event.COMPLETE`. That is dispatched when the download is complete.
Maybe PHP is different, though.

Comment: how we will get the bytes total in complete event?We are trying to read the file using the URLLoader there is no PHP file using for downloading. after reading the file from the server we use FileStream to write the file. Issue is only with the bytesTotal.