# event.bytesTotal returning 0 in ProgressEvent.PROGRESS

Tags: actionscript-3, urlrequest, ftp-server

I am getting the result for `event.bytesTotal = 0` in some of the mp3 file when i am loading it from ftp server.But
when loading the same file from local server, the call to `event.bytesTotal` is working well - giving the expected result.

Here is my code :

```
 public function LoadedBytes()
        {
            var byteLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            byteLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;

            var fileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest();

            myFile =new File();
            myFile=File.desktopDirectory; 
            myFileStream = new FileStream();

            fileRequest.url="http://minhajproductions.in/irfanulquran/Al-Fatihah/4.mp3";

            myFile=File.desktopDirectory;  
            myFile=myFile.resolvePath("sound/4.mp3");

            try{
                byteLoader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,onProgress);
                byteLoader.load(fileRequest);
            }catch(e:IOError){
                trace("unable to load requested sound")
            }



        }

        protected function onProgress(event:ProgressEvent):void
        {
            trace(event.bytesLoaded,event.bytesTotal," length");
            //progressCB((event.bytesLoaded/event.bytesTotal));

        }
```

why this weird thing is happening?
        Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried your code with no change. It is working fine.

Comment: Have you downloaded that sound? What is the size of that sound?
its working at your side may be because i changed 4.mp3 yesterday several times for testing.For sounds whose size is less than 50kb event.bytesTotal is giving correct result but for large file like i have its giving 0. :-(

Comment: I have not downloaded it. I am loading it from the same URL.

Comment: BTW, Are you trying to download that file? Why `File()` and `FileStream()`. Also `myFile=File.desktopDirectory;` is written twice.

Comment: Yes i have to save file.I used File and FileStream to save downloaded file.myFile=File.desktopDirectory(twice) sorry its my mistake.

Comment: Why don't you try `Event.OPEN` or try with `HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS` and check for statuses, or `SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR` so that you can get some light ray in the dark.

Comment: Getting event.status 200 in HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS,no security error.Actually everything is working fine,my file gets saved in desired location but in ProgressEvent bytesTotal value is 0.
And i want to add a downloading Bar so that user can know how much data have been downloaded so for this i need bytesTotal.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was the missing Content-Length header on my server side. Flash use it to be able to find the download progression.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem at your end. Try running the same program from some other place.

I found one post [event-bytestotal-returns-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429212/flex-progress-event-bytestotal-returns-0-in-linux)

Check the first answer in which [Chunked_transfer_encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) link is given for more info.